# How can I dynamically control a Region Display Selector in Oracle APEX?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm hoping to select a particular Region to highlight on the page load based on the link the user follows to get to that page. This is a drill-down report with multiple options, so the goal is to have all options available but focus on the one the user selected to reduce the number of times a user has to navigate to/from the base report to the drill-downs.

Currently, I'm trying to implement this solution [https://svenweller.wordpress.com.../](https://svenweller.wordpress.com/2018/11/27/apex-quickie-set-region-display-selector-dynamically/), further explained in an Oracle Community discussion here: [https://community.oracle.com/...](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4334884/set-region-display-selector-dynamic-on-page-load), but it is not working for me.

What I have now is similar to what is shown in those examples, and for now I'm just trying to link to a static Region Display Selector (RDS) tab (the goal will be to have the selected Region be dynamic based on which link is clicked in the feeder page, but I'm clearly not there yet).

I have a Dynamic Action set to fire on Page Load event, and a True action that executes JavaScript code and uses the JavaScript in the example (both with and without the Timeout function suggested in the Oracle thread). I have set Static IDs for the RDS and Region, but when I load the page the RDS still defaults to Show All (or the first region if Show All is off).

Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

```
let sesStorage = apex.storage.getScopedSessionStorage({
       useAppId:true, 
       usePageId:true});
setTimeout(sesStorage.setItem( "tabs.activeTab", "#R3" ) {    apex.region("tabs").widget().aTabs("getTabs")["#R3"].makeActive();}, 300);

\\version without setTimeout

let sesStorage = apex.storage.getScopedSessionStorage({
       useAppId:true, 
       usePageId:true});
sesStorage.setItem( "tabs.activeTab", "#R3" );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done something like this in the past. Create a hidden variable on the page `P1_TEST`, make sure to set the value not to be protected.

You will need to set the value of that variable when the link is clicked.

Then you need to add static IDs `TAB1`, `TAB2` etc. to the tabs of you region display selector.

Then add a DA on Page Load:

```
if (apex.item("P1_TEST").getValue() === "Value1"){
     $(".apex-rds [href='#TAB1']").trigger('click'); 
} else if (apex.item("P1_TEST").getValue() === "Value2"){
     $(".apex-rds [href='#TAB2']").trigger('click');
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. That still did not work for me, but I've since learned that some (but not all) JS is blocked on our network, and that may be the issue I'm running into, which means that end users likely couldn't benefit regardless.